# How to speed up the creation of a table from table partitioned by date?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with a huge amount of data. It is partitioned by week. This table contains a column named `group`. Each `group` could have multiple records of weeks. For example:

**List item**

```
  gr  week  data
   1     1    10
   1     2    13 
   1     3     5
   .     .     6
   2     2    14 
   2     3    55
   .     .     .
```

I want to create a table based on one `group`. The creation currently is taking ~23 minutes on Oracle 11g. This is a long time since I have to repeat the process for each group and I have many groups.  what is the best fastest way to create the table  ?

Comment: do you need data in both tables - source and destination? Or you will delete data from source table after copy it?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. How exactly are you creating "a table based on one group"? What is "huge" amount of data? What are the table and index definitions? As it stands now, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Yes i need both.  In fact the source table is a physical table and the destination table is a temporary table that will be deleted after using the stored data .

Comment: Each time, i select a group and i create the table based on this group , let say group A. This group a will had data based on the dates. The source table is partitioned by dates and subpartitioned by types (2 types) and contains 3 bilions records. No indexes created on it except i create i bitmap index i thought it might help but no. It is a sales table sku/date/sold units ,…

Comment: Why is it that you're creating this copy of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Create all tables then use INSERT ALL WHEN
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2145081

The data will be read only once.

```
insert all
  when gr=1 then
  into tab1 values (gr, week, data)
  when gr=2 then
  into tab2 values (gr, week, data)
  when gr=3 then
  into tab3 values (gr, week, data)
select *
from big_table
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is i am dealing with ~ 3 billion records , i will blow the tablespace.  I have to create a table from one group and when i finished working from that group i drop the table and create a table for different group and so on.  Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The best speed up you reach if you don't copy the data on group basis and process then week by week, but you don't say what you will reach so it is not possible to comment (this approach may be of course difficult or impracticable; but you should at least consider it).

Therefore below some hints how to extract the group data:

- remove all indexes as this will only block space - all you need to do is one large **FULL TABLE SCAN**
- check the available space and size of each group; maybe you can process several groups in one pass
- deploy parallel query

.

```
 create table tmp as
 select /*+ parallel(4) */ * from BIG_TABLE
 where group_id in (..list of groupIds..);
```

Please note that parallel mode must be enabled in the database, ask your DBA if you are unsure. The point is that the large FULL TABLE SCAN is performed by several sub-processes (here 4) which may (dependent on your mileage) cut the elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you Marmite. I have already tested your first approach, its' much easier but unfortunately, i don't have too much space to do that,  creating all the groups week by week. Creating one week for a selected group will take ~1 min and i have 104 weeks , which means 1h and half( i am creating a process and the time allowed to run it will not exceed 36 hours)  As for your second approach,  it is worth to think about it,   i have to tested tomorrow to check  the performance

Comment: Good luck and let us know if we can help.